# При перегрузке = возможно ли изменить правый операнд если он передан по константной ссылке

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, const

Почему допускается изменить правый операнд в оператора равно, то есть работает это:    ++*h.use;
Правый операнд является константной ссылкой и не может использовать модифицирующие операторы типа ++.

```
H& H::operator=(const H& h) {
    ++*h.use;
    if (--*use == 0) {
        delete ps;
        delete use;
    }

    ps = h.ps;
    i = h.i;
    use = h.use;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь вы никак не меняете сам объект `h`, а меняете значение, на которое указывает его член-указатель `use`. Оператор инкремента применяется к разыменованному указателю `*h.use`.

Вот если бы объявили `use` как указатель на константное значение — тогда дело другое. Сейчас же константность `h` не под угрозой :)